# fresh start issues in phonegap

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm a new user of Phonegap and I'm very confused how everything works. I have created the project on `c://ProjectName` and **built it for android**. I open my ADT (Eclipse) and I create a project from the existing code, then I have two project folders : ProjectName  and ProjectName-CordovaLib.

- First Question:
  What is ProjectName-CordovaLib? Will I ever need to code inside of that folder ?
- Second Question:
  I have in ProjectName>www files , I'm familiar with as web programmer.
  CSS JS IMG and html files.

When I modify the index.html file and run the app in the emulator, it doesn't seem to have any effect. in ADT the auto-rebuild option is checked. How am I able to modify the file ? 
In : ProjectName.java

```
public class ProjectName extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

I think these are my problems at the moment. Can you help me please? 
My index.html file (Modified):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>MY APP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>MY</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Hi !</p>
                <p class="event received">Hello Sekai</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //there was something here but I deleted it.
        // there was an app.init() 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Properties of project]

Comment: Please show me the code of index.html file also

Comment: I posted the modified index.html

Comment: I also renamed the index to index1 , but it didn't alert a not found error, but when I changed `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");`
To 
`super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index1.html");`
It alerted the error.
so, WTF is android_asset ? isn't it in the project I created in the console ?

Comment: do you import project in Eclipse

Comment: It's the android "distribution" of Eclipse from Google Android package , but yes it's Eclipse

Comment: either use   super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl()); or use  super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); to call index.html from webview.

Comment: Used both possibilities but doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: where is "file:///android_asset/www/index.html" located ?

Answer (score 1):

First Ans: What is `ProjectName-CordovaLib`?  -> It is the library ot cordoava. in olderversion phongap will provide .jar and now andorid 3.3.0 up it will provide one library.

Second Ans: I have in `ProjectName>www ->` it the basic common code to use in multiple platform,

In Android you can see www in assets forlder. if not than read "`_where-is-www.txt`" file and follow instraction.

Comment: Please refer to the question again , I've attached a picture of configuration , I don't understand what's in there

Comment: you can select projectrelated path and remove both

Comment: I don't understand , they are already excluded should i remove them ?